# Nullpointerexception because of measuring time?

Tags: java, android, button, nullpointerexception

I want to measure the time between first button click and third button click. The code itself works fine, bur when I click the Button the 3rd time on my device, I'm getting a nullpointerexception.

why?

here's the code:

```
public class Game extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

Button start_time;

int i = 0;
TextView textview1;

Button RelativeLayout;
Button gameover;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//  RelativeLayout.setClickable(true);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
      start_time = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_time);
      start_time.setOnClickListener(this);
      textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
      gameover = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gameover);


      gameover.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                finish();


            }


            });



}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.game, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override


public void onClick(View v) {

     textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    Random r = new Random();
    RelativeLayout decorView = (RelativeLayout) start_time.getParent();
    int screenWidth = decorView.getWidth();
    int screenHeight = decorView.getHeight();
      long startTime =  SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
      i++;


    if (i == 1 ) {

        start_time.setX(r.nextInt(screenWidth - start_time.getWidth()));
        start_time.setY(r.nextInt(screenHeight - start_time.getHeight()));
    }
    if (i == 2 ) {
        start_time.setX(r.nextInt(screenWidth - start_time.getWidth()));
        start_time.setY(r.nextInt(screenHeight - start_time.getHeight()));
    }
    if (i == 3 ) {
        start_time.setX(r.nextInt(screenWidth - start_time.getWidth()));
        start_time.setY(r.nextInt(screenHeight - start_time.getHeight()));
    }
    if (i == 4 ) {
        start_time.setX(r.nextInt(screenWidth - start_time.getWidth()));
        start_time.setY(r.nextInt(screenHeight - start_time.getHeight()));
    }
    if (i == 5 ) {
        start_time.setX(r.nextInt(screenWidth - start_time.getWidth()));
        start_time.setY(r.nextInt(screenHeight - start_time.getHeight()));
    }
    if (i == 6 ) {
        start_time.setX(r.nextInt(screenWidth - start_time.getWidth()));
        start_time.setY(r.nextInt(screenHeight - start_time.getHeight()));
    }
    else if (i == 7) {
        long difference = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()  - startTime;

          Intent intent = new Intent(Game.this, MainScreen.class);
          intent.putExtra("time",difference);

        // textview1.setText(intent.getStringExtra("time"));
      //   textview1.setText(String.valueOf(difference));
        finish();
    }


}
```

}

and the mainactivity :

```
public class MainScreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button btn_start;
TextView textview1;




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);


    btn_start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_start);
    btn_start.setOnClickListener(this);
    textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(this,Game.class), 0);
    textview1.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("time"));  
}
```

}

logcat:

```
03-09 16:08:10.760: E/AndroidRuntime(6372): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-09 16:08:10.760: E/AndroidRuntime(6372): Process: ch.frozensparks.asdf, PID: 6372
03-09 16:08:10.760: E/AndroidRuntime(6372): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-09 16:08:10.760: E/AndroidRuntime(6372):     at ch.frozensparks.bftjh.Game.onClick(Game.java:118)
03-09 16:08:10.760: E/AndroidRuntime(6372):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4470)
03-09 16:08:10.760: E/AndroidRuntime(6372):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18593)
03-09 16:08:10.760: E/AndroidRuntime(6372):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-09 16:08:10.760: E/AndroidRuntime(6372):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-09 16:08:10.760: E/AndroidRuntime(6372):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
```

Comment: Where is `start_time` defined? I only see a `long startTime`, which is a **long** and indeed will never expose any `getWidth()` or `getHeight()` methods.

Comment: textview1 is initiated?

Comment: "the code itself works fine" - not really.

getIntent() is probably where you're getting the nullPointer. What is the purpose behind getIntent? Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: updated code in question

Comment: I putted the logcat in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is occuring on this line

```
textview1.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("time"));
```

You are trying to getIntent from the current activity but passing to new intent object here

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Game.this, MainScreen.class);
          intent.putExtra("time",difference);
```

Comment: sorry, the textview1 is on my mainactivity. updated code

Comment: what value u get from getIntent().getStringExtra("time")?

Comment: sorry...i don't really understand...do you mean 'time' ?     intent.putExtra("time",difference);     i also put the logcat in the q

Comment: Thanks @Fahim. I've marked your answer as correct. If you think my question contributes towards SO, please concider to upvote it!

Answer (score 1):

(First of all, I'm assuming that the code at the top of your post is part of Game.class.)

Ok I think you're misunderstanding how intents function.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Game.this, MainScreen.class);
    intent.putExtra("time", difference);
```

Here you're creating a new intent (called 'intent') and putting the value 'difference' with the key 'time' inside it.

Then

```
    textview1.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("time"));
```

Here you're trying to access that value -- but you're actually accessing a completely different intent object. By using getIntent() you're accessing the intent object used to start the current activity, not the one you defined above it. (Also you're attempting to get a String extra from the intent, but you're storing a long.)

If you want to access that intent object, simply use:

```
intent.getStringExtra("time");
```

So your line would be:

```
textview1.setText(intent.getStringExtra("time"));
```

But instead I would just do this:

```
textview1.setText(String.valueOf(difference));
```

Last thing, I can't be sure where you're defining textview1 in the top chunk of code, but if you're trying to refer to the textview1 that is a part of MainScreen that could be causing your problem, so you may have to make it public or pass the difference variable back and set the text in MainScreen.

Comment: thanks. now I changed the code, trying to solve it, and the nullpointer is gone! but i am not getting any sort of numbers, where the time should be displayed...it's just empty. the // is what i already tried

Comment: The text is probably white, displaying on a white background - try setting the colour. Can you set any text to the textview1 (just try putting 'test' or some other string in there)?  Are you certain that you have the correct TextView as textview1 - and not some other one?

Answer (score -1):

You need to finish yoir MainScreen Activity when navigating to Game. 
     MainScreen.this.finish(); in onClick method of MainScreen.

Also you need to start the activity in onclick of game activity

```
startActivity(intent)
```